# Access to Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

I have to write a small reservation web app to be used inside the company where I work. I decided to try out Google Apps Script (GAS). In short, the user must be able to select any equipment in a list and submit it along with a date he's planning to use it and his identification (this small system must implement the complete CRUD).

The environment:

- Google Spreadsheet as a database
- Interface made with GAS published as a Web App
- The app will be accessible just to members of the company's domain, but I'm developing it in my personal account for now.

In the development environment, everything works fine. Then I deploy it as web app the project (Execute app as: Me; Who has access to the app: anyone). When anyone acess the link, I can't retrieve the user information (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()). It always retrive the developer information (my information). If I switch the "Execute app as" to "User accessing the app", then the app can't access the spreadsheet that is making the role of the database. In the development environment this works fine.

The rest of the web app is working fine. I just wanted to get and record the identity (email) of who made de reservation in an automatic way (not by asking the user to type this information).

Do I have to setup something else before people can access it?

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT 1]:** The situation changed a little bit. I made a few more tests and it seems that the deployed web app get updated just when I save it as a new version in the project. Anyway, I still can't retrieve the active user email. The Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() now returns a blank string.

**[EDIT 2]:** Following Sujay Phadke's answer [bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39192463/6433166), I tried migrating the web app to the company's environment. It worked like a charm.

Juliano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's well documented here: [getActiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser())

When the webapp permissions are set as "execute as me", it seems that the returned userid string will be empty. It also depends on your specific domain permissions as mentioned there.

Comment: I've just read the link, @Sujay Phadke: "_(...) the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets, **or a web app deployed to "execute as me"** (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However, **these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer and the user belong to the same Google Apps for Business domain**._".

Comment: I'll made some tests in the company's environment because there I can ask for the TI administrator to change the security policy if it's necessary. Thank you.

Comment: it's going to work in your domain, I use the same configuration in a Google Apps Education domain without problem. The webapp runs as me, I use `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` to get the enduser ID